# Ruby on Rails path to public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site that was developed in ROR by a friend. He put it on a linux server. I have root access and I am trying to figure out the path to the public public folder. Is there any standard path for ROR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just SSHed into the server, you'll have to hunt for it. There's no ONE standard location where rails apps are installed. We follow the convention of installing our apps in /u/.

I suggest you do "ps -ef | grep " to see if that gives you some hint about running processes reading files from a certain location.

You can try runnning "find / -name 'application.rb'" to look for a Railsy app folder.

Comment: Or, you could try to search for environment.rb if they're using rails < 3.